# How to perform facebook Login without permissions?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, permissions

i am using the java/android facebook login sdk 5.5.1. The  `LoginManager.getInstance().login(activity, permissions)` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/login/loginmanager.html/)  returns a cancelled login state when i try to pass an empty array of permissions to that method.

I truly don't need an email or any other details from the facebook user's profile. I only need the accesstoken + userid.

How can i realise that behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask for `public_profile`.

That is the absolute “minimum” permission needed to access *any* user details, even the ID. It is usually applied by default without having to be specifically asked for, but if you can’t pass an empty scope value with SDK you are using, then set that one explicitly.